# How can I connect on my own PC to a local FileZilla FTP server for testings?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ftp

I downloaded the FileZilla Server and installed it.

Then I use in FileZilla as address: 127.0.0.1 port: 14147 and admin user name: admin

And it connected fine.
But now I want to connect to the server upload download and delete files using C#.

This is my code. This code was working fine when I used my online FTP server at ipage.com

But now I want to use it with the FileZilla.

```
string fff = "";
public string[] GetFileList()
{
    string[] downloadFiles;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    WebResponse response = null;
    StreamReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
        reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + f.Host + "/"));
        fff = "ftp://" + f.Host + "/";
        reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
        reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(f.Username, f.Password);
        reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
        reqFTP.Proxy = null;
        reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
        reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
        response = reqFTP.GetResponse();
        reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            result.Append(line);
            result.Append("\n");
            line = reader.ReadLine();
        }
        result.Remove(result.ToString().LastIndexOf('\n'), 1);
        return result.ToString().Split('\n');
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (reader != null)
        {
            reader.Close();
        }
        if (response != null)
        {
            response.Close();
        }
        downloadFiles = null;
        return downloadFiles;
    }
}
```

In `fff` I see `ftp://127.0.0.1/` and `f.Username` is empty `""` and `f.Password` is `admin`

Then I make continue and I'm getting exception:

```
The remote server returned an error: (501) Syntax error in parameters or arguments

System.Net.WebException was caught
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The remote server returned an error: (501) Syntax error in parameters or arguments.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.CheckError()
       at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
       at System.IO.Stream.Close()
       at System.Net.ConnectionPool.Destroy(PooledStream pooledStream)
       at System.Net.ConnectionPool.PutConnection(PooledStream pooledStream, Object owningObject, Int32 creationTimeout, Boolean canReuse)
       at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.FinishRequestStage(RequestStage stage)
       at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()
       at FTP_ProgressBar.FtpProgress.GetFileList() in c:\ftp_progressbar\FTP_ProgressBar\FtpProgress.cs:line 342
  InnerException:
```

Line 342 is:

```
response = reqFTP.GetResponse();
```

What I want is to demo FTP server so I can check my C# program on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `501` is likely sent by the FileZilla server due to an absence of username in `USER` command. You cannot login to FTP server without providing a username.

You have to login with FTP account to the server. You cannot login with an administrative password.

In FileZilla Server Interface, go to menu *Edit > Users*, create an FTP user, and use it's username/password in your code.